# Can't compile OpenCV in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV and I just want to use `UIImageToMat`.

**ENV**

Xcode 8.3.3
Swift 3.0
OpenCV 3.2.0

**ERROR**

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group  
"UIImageToMat(UIImage const*, cv::Mat&, bool)", referenced from:  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**I tried following things.**

- Precompile Prefix Header changed to Yes.
- Add pch file into prefix header.
- C++ Standard Library changed to libc++.

If I removed UIImageToMat, I can compile sources.
Maybe, I have problem in my setting.

Any Idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV UIImageToMat linker fail in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799132/opencv-uiimagetomat-linker-fail-in-xcode)

Comment: Can you try this: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with xCode 9 beta 2 so maybe my solution will fix your problem.

- Instead of drag and drop the openCV framework, I install it with Cocoapods. 
   [How to use Cocoapods.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156971/cocoapods-tutorial-swift-getting-started)
- Notice that the version 3.2 generates some issues, 3.1.0.1 is working fine. 
   Write this line on your Podfile :

  *pod 'OpenCV' '~> 3.1.0.1'*
- Deactivate BITCODE on both Pods target and your project. 
   Build Settings > Search "BITCODE" > Enable Bitcode : **No**

Comment: I could compile by using ver '3.1.0.1'. Thank you so much!